# Bloomberg data api how to include library c++

Tags: c++, api, c++11, gcc, bloomberg

When I run the compile a program using the Bloomberg data api I get a large number of errors. I don't know how to include the blpapi properly.

Command line:

```
g++ SimpleHistoryExample.cpp -I ../include/
```

Comment: I don't know what bloomberg is, but don't you have to compile a static library first in order to link against it? It seems like your linker can't find anything, which is usually a sign of that.

Comment: Nowhere in this command line`g++ SimpleHistoryExample.cpp -I ../include/` do you tell g++ to link in the library. There should be a `-l<name of library>` in there somewhere. (and probably a `-L <path to library>`)

Comment: Yeah, that could be it too. I thought that he completely forgot to build the library (as I do sometimes, lol). But simply not linking against it could be it as well.

Answer (score 1):

In order to link in a static library you need to specify where the library can be found with the `-L` option and then specify which library to link with `-l`.

```
g++ -L <insert path to library here> -I../include/ SimpleHistoryExample.cpp -l<name of library (blpapi?)>
```